# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null :(

Tags: javascript

i think that the code 100% normal but why i got that Error????:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null||

the code is:

```
<!DoCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset ="utf-8">
    <meta name="" content="">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function myAgeInDays() {
        
        "use strict";
        
        var myAge = 15;
        
        return myAge * 365;
    
    }
    
    var daysCalc = myAgeInDays();
    
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
    
        "Your Age In Days = "+ daysCalc+ " Day";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="myinfo();">OK</button>
    <h1 id="test">Ok</h1>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `script` after the element it references.

Comment: try put a "defer" in your script tag or move the script tag an the end of your body

Comment: Never seen a combination of script src="" and actual inline script. Don't know if you have pasted all the code, but the fiddle where i pasted code is good, check. https://jsfiddle.net/m23owq54/

Comment: It is very unfortunate to say so, but I am a beginner in the JavaScript language

Comment: Jayr, i have pasted what i typed from the src file

Comment: Heretic Monkey , no it is not

Comment: @Syder `defer` can only be used side by side with `src`. It cannot be used on inline scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted does not work (myinfo is not defined) and your code is in the `<head>` which is defined before the `<p>` is created. add it at the end of your body to ensure that all the elements are created. If you wanted to make a function handle the button click that contained the logic in your , you would write something like:

```html
<body>
  <button id="calcDays">OK</button>
  <h1 id="test">Ok</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('calcDays')
      .addEventListener('click', function () {
          function myAgeInDays(days) {
            return days * 365;
          }

          document.getElementById("test").textContent =
            `Your Age In Days = ${myAgeInDays(15)} Days`;
      });
  </script>
</body>
```